# Can I put a 2x10 ceiling joist Douglas Fir#1 at 21-6 span at 24 on center?

Tags: framing, ceiling, garage, joists, construction

In my garage I have a span of 21 feet and 6 inches with 2x8 rafters.
Can I put a 2x10 ceiling joists on 24OC for an ADU? They will be sitting in the top plate of the walls.

I am in California, and they are uninhabitable attic ceiling joists not floor joists. I was looking at the california building code and it says im allowed up to 23-6 on 24 centers.

Comment: Is there a specific reason you want 24" centers?  If it isn't just trying to economise, there may be better ways to achieve your goal.

Comment: 3/4" OSB provides a nice stiff floor surface with joists on 16" centers. 24" centers is probably a mistake. 1-1/8 plywood works to get sufficient stiffness over 24" spans, but it's much more expensive than OSB. I suppose you could use 3/4" OSB right on its 24" span rating, but that alone isn't stiff enough to meet floor stiffness specs without an upper layer of underlayment. The only persuasive rationalization that I can conjure for 24" joist spacing is if your walls have single top plates with studs on 24" centers.

Comment: Please take the [tour]. This isn't a discussion forum and you shouldn't have posted your clarification as an answer. It's also in appropriate to request personal contact.

Comment: So the ADU is on the slab, not above the garage? Are you familiar with the fine print that distinguishes uninhabitable attics with storage from those without storage (footnotes at https://up.codes/viewer/california/ca-residential-code-2022/chapter/3/building-planning#R301.5)? You're installing ceiling joists so that you can drywall and insulate the ceiling? Do you currently have a structural ridge beam to support the 2x8 rafters? There aren't any rafter ties? Or are you looking to replace/add-to the rafter ties?

Comment: Yes, drywall and insulate the ceiling, there are rafter ties but no structural ridge beam. Its just a 2x10 as a ridge beam

Answer (score 3):

No way. For a sleeping room or habitable attic with the standard 30 psf live load and with a 10 psf dead load, your #1 grade Doug Fir 2x10s on 24" centers have a max span of 15'-0". 12" centers only get that up to 20'-3". Outside of sleeping rooms and habitable attics, the standard live load goes up to 40 psf and you would be even further out of bounds.

See the tables under [IRC R502.3](https://codes.iccsafe.org/content/IRC2021P2/chapter-5-floors#IRC2021P2_Pt03_Ch05_SecR502.3) to size your joists. For sleeping rooms and habitable attics, you want the first table, Table R502.3.1(1). For habitable spaces other than sleeping rooms and attics, you want the second table, Table R502.3.1(2).

For a floor assembly with joists on 16" centers, 3/4" OSB on top, and 1/2" drywall underneath, your dead load (before carpet, tile, etc.) is

2.5psf + (1.5")(1ft/12")(d)(1ft/12")(0.50)(62.4#/ft<sup>3</sup>) / [(16")(1ft/12")] + 1.6psf = **4.1 + 0.24d (psf)**,

where d is the joist height in inches. The 10 psf dead load columns from those IRC tables are usually what you want to use.